# Resize varchar doesn't update crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, sql-update

I've got an existing report with quite a few fields on it.

I have just modified my database changing a varchar(10) to a varchar(20)

When I test it out with data '12345678901234567890' the query against my view works perfectly fine. However, even after I've completed a "Verify Database" it doesn't display the whole value.

I have attempted using a formula to display it, it still truncates it at 10 characters, I have also done a LEN({myfield}) and it displays 10.

I have also used the command "Update datasource location".

Somehow that field length information is stuck.

Comment: This may be a dumb suggestion, but have you tried manually resizing the field after verifying the database?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would manually resize the field, any idea's?

Comment: Slightly belated answer - assuming you have opened the report in report designer and have just verified the database, click on the field in question so that it is visibly selected, then hover the cursor over the edges of the field so that it turns into a <-> character - this is when it can resize the field. (If it turns into cross-hairs, it will reposition the field instead.) Click and drag the field boundaries to the new size.

Comment: @Mark, the field was physically sized properly. The data in the field was truncated at 10 characters.

Comment: @Nathan, I said it might be a dumb suggestion! Glad you figured it out anyway...

Comment: @Mark, thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it in a roundabout way.

1. I removed this field from my datasource,
2. I then verified the database and the field was removed from the report
3. I then re-added the field to the datasource
4. Then re-added the field to the report

Everything displayed properly.